# Vue3 failing to build project because can't resolve module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, anime.js

I'm using animeJS in my Vue3 project. I'm currently importing it only within the component I'm using it, and it functions fine over local host. However, in the import statement, I do get the warning:

Could not find a declaration file for module 'animejs/lib/anime.es.js'. 'path/to/node_modules/animejs/lib/anime.es.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.

And when I try to run `npm run build`, I get the following error:

```
error  in ./src/components/HeroSection.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'animejs/lib/anime.es.js' in 'path/to/src/components'
```

How can I get Vue to recognize the import? Because animeJS is working fine over local host, I was expecting `npm run build` to compile properly.

Comment: Have you tried installing its declaration files:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/animejs

Comment: @CarlosJafetNeto Thanks for the reply! I have and it has not worked unfortunately. I also tried require() statements and those don't seem to work either. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Do you have your project in GitHub?